# More efficient error catching?

Tags: vb.net, performance, if-statement, combobox

So I am at an internship for school that is having me code a program using VB.NET. One of the forms has three combo boxes that must have a choice selected in each before moving on. If the user missed one of the comboboxes I am trying to bring it to their attention to go back and make a selection before continuing. I have an if statement, which works exactly how I want it to:

```
If cboYear.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        warningString = warningString + "Year" & vbNewLine & "Vendor" & vbNewLine & "Report"
        txtYear.ForeColor = Color.Red
        TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Red
        txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Red
        MessageBox.Show(warningString)
    ElseIf cboVendorName.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        warningString = warningString + "Vendor" + vbNewLine & "Report"
        txtYear.ForeColor = Color.Black
        TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Red
        txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Red
        MessageBox.Show(warningString)
    ElseIf cboReport.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        warningString = warningString + "Report" & vbNewLine
        txtYear.ForeColor = Color.Black
        TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Black
        txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Red
        MessageBox.Show(warningString)
    Else
        Main.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
```

(warningString is a generic string that says something like "Please fill in the following:")

So like I said this works exactly how I want it to, and its pretty easy to follow my logic here. My question is how can I make this code more efficient? I have tried arrays to hold combobox selections, and I have tried a for loop and a select case to try and streamline the code to no avail. The array always breaks out and returns a NullReferenceException before it gets to my Select Case or For loop to see if there is a value in the combobox or not.

If there is someone out there who can help walk me through the logic of getting some kind of loop to work for the above, that would be awesome. I'm not asking for working code or anything like that, however if there is a solution to be found and I get there myself I will post it here for future reference for people. Who knows, this might even be the most efficient way already?

**Edit:** Plutonix has been gracious enough to have offered some comments on my question, and he brought up a point about the if statements not being mutually exclusive. That is because the comboboxes are being populated by datasets, and each CBO in order determines what information from the datasets will populate the next one. So, depending on what year is selected in the 'Year' combobox, determines which vendors populate the 'Vendor' combobox, and that determines which reports are populated in the 'Report' combobox.

Comment: VB6 does not have a `NullReferenceException`  are you sure you arent using VB.NET

Comment: No it is for sure vb6, I just tried running the Select Case and here is what Visual Studio told me: An unhandled exception type 'System.NullReferenceException' occured in ETL.exe ****** Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It is an object array that holds for example: errorArray(0) = cboYear.SelectedIndex, and then the Select Case testexpression is -1

Comment: Sorry, but there was no such thing as `System.NullReferenceException` in VB6.  You are using VB.NET; look at Help | About on the IDE menu for the name/version.  You should note that your IFs are not mutually exclusive: they can have missed a selection in more than one CBO

Comment: Well you are actually correct, the program contains .vbproj files which after a bit of research is a .NET extension! However my partner and I have exclusively (to our knowledge) been using vb6 code, which must still be compatible with .NET (the working code in the program I mean, I know not all vb6 is compatible). This is all a bit embarrassing, so thank you for pointing that out, the tag on the question has been updated.

Comment: On the if statements, yes you are correct on that as well. However, and I should have made mention of this in my question, each combobox in order from the first one down must be selected in order to fill the next combobox from a dataset: the first 'year' combobox determines which vendors to fill the 'vendor' combobox, which determines which reports to fill the 'report' combobox, etc. So if the first combobox is not changed, that means no combobox is changed because they would not have had values populated in the first place. I will clarify that point in an edit to the original question.

Comment: `you are actually correct`: it can happen on occasion.  Since the code is checking different things and doing different things, a loop would be unwieldy.  Since more than one condition can be true, break it into 3 standalone `If/Then`s.  You dont say where that code is located but even if you have enabled them one at a time, you can use the same code block anytime any CBO changes (including changing a previous selection!)

Comment: See that was what I was wondering, since they are indeed checking different things! I could only begin to grasp the logic of a loop in this instance, but kept getting caught up at that point, ie how to account for different parameters on each pass of the loop. I was hoping there was a better way because of other implications, there is another form in the program with 13 different comboboxes/textboxes that need the same kind of error handling (I posted the easier one with only 3 comboboxes). I will post your comment as the answer if you don't mind, thank you so much for helping me today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each test is doing something different a loop would be clumsy.  Even if you only enable B once A is validated, you might need to allow for them to UnDo a previous selection.  The code can be condensed though:

```
Dim IsValid As Boolean = True
txtYear.ForeColor = Color.Black
TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Black
txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Black

If cboYear.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    warningString = warningString & "Year" & vbNewLine & "Vendor" & vbNewLine & "Report"
    txtYear.ForeColor = Color.Red
    TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Red
    txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Red
    IsValid = False
End If

If cboVendorName.Enabled AndAlso cboVendorName.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    warningString = warningString & "Vendor" & vbNewLine & "Report"
    TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Red
    txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Red
    IsValid = False
End If

If cboReport.Enabled AndAlso cboReport.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    warningString = warningString & "Report" & vbNewLine
    txtReport.ForeColor = Color.Red
    IsValid = False
End If

'  See note
If IsValid = False Then
    MessageBox.Show(warningString)
Else
    ' DONT use default form instances!
    Main.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End If
```

The `IF` changed a bit: I dont know how you tell which ones are active, the code above is using `.Enabled` to see if each has been set up for use.  That way you wont report errors on CBO 2 and 3 when validating #1.

I would make it a function which `Returns IsValid` and let the calling code manage the forms to show...and dont use default form instances.

Comment: You might also want to look at the ErrorProvider.  It will put a little red `!` next to the bad stuff

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your help. This is the answer, as Plutonix explained earlier a loop would be too unwieldy for all the different information being checked. So in this situation If statements are indeed the way to go, and the above code is a better representation of what I was going for.